# Curl::Multi.download is broken?

Tags: ruby, curl, curb

When I do

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > Curl::Multi.download(["http://www.bbc.com"])
=> nil
```

The downloaded file is of zero size

```
ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 staff  0 Jan  5 19:51 www.bbc.com
```

But the same works with Curl::Easy.download

```
Curl::Easy.download("http://www.bbc.com")
=> #<Curl::Easy http://www.bbc.com> 

ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 staff  111549 Jan  5 19:53 www.bbc.com
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not - `Curl::Multi.http` (and `Curl::Multi.download` as well, since it actually calls `Curl::Multi.http`) have been broken in Curb since version 0.7.15.

This totally baffled me for awhile but I figured out what was wrong and have submitted a patch (see https://github.com/taf2/curb/pull/115).

Hopefully this gets merged upstream - in the meantime, you should stick to Curb 0.7.14 and below.

UPDATE: My pull request has been merged: https://github.com/taf2/curb/commit/dceafcd931c4fb7ad2c8d356537358fd1286e4ae - you can grab `curb/master` for the fix.